# sessionStorage doesn't work with JSON.stringify or ?

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't this work ?

```
function VarsStorage(act,varname,val){
  if(act == 'get'){
    return sessionStorage.getItem(varname+'Cache');
  }else if(act == 'set'){
    sessionStorage.setItem(varname+'Cache', val);   
  }
}

VarsStorage('set','addStocksList',JSON.stringify(holder));
```

I try many combinations of this code and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Because `holder` isn't defined anywhere?

Comment: what is holder?

Comment: Doesn't work means what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set works for me:

```
var holder = { ... };

VarsStorage('set','addStocksList',JSON.stringify(holder));
```

But if you're getting a serialized object from storage, you have to parse the string into an object using `JSON.parse`:

```
var holder = JSON.parse(VarsStorage('get','addStocksList'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working perfectly, just set the `holder`

```
function VarsStorage(act,varname,val){
  if(act == 'get'){
    return sessionStorage.getItem(varname+'Cache');
  }else if(act == 'set'){
    sessionStorage.setItem(varname+'Cache', val);   
  }
}

var holder = { "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"};
VarsStorage('set','addStocksList',JSON.stringify(holder));

VarsStorage('get','addStocksList');
//return
//"{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}"
```